# Side of a square inscribed in regular polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons

> I'm trying to derive a general formula for the side of a square inscribed in a regular polygon with $n$ sides.
>
> I know there may be more than one, e.g. infinitely-many for an octagon, but I want to be able to extract the side for at least one of them.

I am aware of Dilworth and Mane's 2010 paper ["Inscribing a regular $m$-gon in a regular $n$-gon" (PDF link via sc.edu)](http://people.math.sc.edu/dilworth/preprints_files/DilworthManeJOGpublished.pdf), but there is no indication on how to calculate the side.

Second part:

> Is it true that for an odd $n$ there is no inscribed square that is concentric with the polygon?

Comment: You surely mind a **maximal** side square, because for example, there are many different sizes of squares inscribed in a square...

Comment: The second part of your Question is interesting, but let's focus on the calculation you want in the first part.  Have you done the computation for a regular octagon?  For a regular hexagon?  Think about where a line $y=x$ will intersect a regular polygon suitably "aligned" with coordinate axes.

Comment: @JeanMarie maximal would also work, but describing any inscribed square would do (n>5 are the interesting cases here).

Comment: For the last part - how you define center of a polygon? The claim seems to be true.

Comment: I am not sure how you define "calculation" - you may have a geometrical construction that provides the means to solve a complex system of equation - such as inscribing an equilateral triangle in another triangle.

Comment: The second claim seems to be right

Comment: To exhibit a construction for any $n$ is not difficult. But that doesn't mean we can find a "nice" formula for the length of the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem (the first part) is a simple version of one posed some one hundred years ago, called the [Inscribed Square Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem) or the [Square Peg Problem](https://www.ams.org/notices/201404/rnoti-p346.pdf).  In full generality that problem is still unsolved.

It is to our advantage that regular polygons are convex. For convenience we can assume the vertices of our regular $n$-gon are equally spaced points on the unit circle around the origin:

$$ (1,0),\;(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right),\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)),\; \ldots (\cos\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right),\sin\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)) $$

### Case: n divisible by four

The easiest case to "calculate" is when $n$ is a multiple of four, e.g. the regular octagon mentioned in the Question.  We can choose any point on the perimeter of the regular $n$-gon and rotate around the polygon through $n/4$ edges to locate successive points (until we return to the originally chosen point).  The four points so chosen will form a square.

If $(x,y)$ is the point initially chosen on the $n$-gon (where $4|n$), and the polygon is centered on the origin, then the next points appears at right-angle rotations, given by:

$$ (x,y),\;(y,-x),\;(-x,-y),\;(-y,x) $$

The maximum area is achieved in this case if the initial point $(x,y)$ is chosen to be a vertex of the (origin-centered) regular $n$-gon.

### Case: n divisible by two but not by four

If $n$ is even but not a multiple of $4$, then the regular $n$-gon described by our vertices above is *symmetric with respect to both* the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis.  Note that while vertices $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ are on the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis intersects the polygon at midpoints of two parallel edges.

We are interested in the points where $y=x$ intersects the polygon.  The vertices of our polygon which "straddle" this line correspond (in the first quadrant) to the angles:

$$ \frac{2\pi k}{n} \lt \frac{\pi}{4} \lt \frac{2\pi (k+1)}{n} $$

Stated more simply, this says $k \lt n/8 \lt k+1$, so $k= \lfloor n/8 \rfloor$.

The equation for the edge, passing through these points:

$$ (\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right),\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)),\;(\cos\left(\frac{2(k+1)\pi}{n}\right),\sin\left(\frac{2(k+1)\pi}{n}\right)) $$

can then be solved with $y=x$ to determine a point of intersection $(r,r)$ on the polygon.  An inscribed square is then given by corners:

$$ (r,r),\;(-r,r),\;(-r,-r),\;(r,-r) $$

which belong to the polygon by virtue of its symmetry with respect to the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis.

### Case: n is odd (not divisible by two)

TBD

Answer (score 0):

Dilworth and Mane publish another paper
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00022-011-0065-3
This gives the maximal regular m-gon in a regular n-gon.
If gcd(m,n) > 1 the problem is completely solved.
If gcd(m,n)=1 the result is stated as a conjecture (which passes numerical checks).
Fixing m=4 gives the answer, except for n=5 and n=9 the maximal square has only three points of contact (= not inscribed).
For all other n \ge 3 the maximal square has four points of contact.
The formula for the edge length is given.

Second part:
For gcd(m,n)=1 the maximal m-gon is never concentric with the n-gon.
Concentric inscribed square for odd n --- see Prop 4.1?